# Finding a vector in a n.l.s.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $Y$ a closed proper subspace. Prove that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $x \in X$ with $\|x\| = 1$ and such that $\|x − y\| ≥ 1 − \varepsilon$ for all $y \in Y$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic result in functional analysis sometimes called [Riesz's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27_lemma). You should be able to find the statement and proof in most functional analysis texts.  For instance this is the Lemma on page two in Joseph Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*.  A Google search reveals a standard (it seems) proof of this result on page 10 [here](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnlfafolder/lfa03.pdf).

If you just want a (big) hint:

Assume $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ (the result is trivial for $\epsilon\ge1$).
Pick any $x$ in $X\setminus Y$. Then the distance $d$ from $x$ to $Y$ is positive (we use the hypothesis that $Y$ is closed here). Thus, you may choose a $z\in Y$ with $0\lt\Vert x-z\Vert <{d\over 1-\epsilon}$.  Consider the vector $x-z\over\Vert x-z\Vert$.